# How do I get intellisense, auto-completion to work for PyGObject library installed in virtual venv on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, pygobject

```
OS = Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit LTS
VSCode version = 1.59.0
```

In the following code at '<<<<<<<< HERE' limited intellisense/auto-completion occurs.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
window.??? <<<<<<<< HERE
window.show()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gtk.main()
```

I installed the following packages using pip3 in a virtual environment in VSCode terminal:

```
pip3 install Pycairo
pip3 install PyGObject
pip3 install SQLAlchemy==1.4.22
pip3 install psutil
pip3 install pexpect
pip3 install websockets
pip3 install PyGobject PGObject-stubs
```

After installing PyGobject PGObject-stubs I could see the following after `window.` :

```
window.__new__
window.__annotations__
window.__class__
window.__delattr__
```

and other `"__xxx__"` options, but no regular options like connect, show, add, resize, etc.

This is my settings.json code in the .vscode directory:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3.9",
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf", // or "black" here
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
    }
}
```

What must I do to have VSCode recognize auto-completion for the PyGOject library?

Comment: Did you select the interpreter inside the virtual environment? Bring up the command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P) and begin to type "Python: Select Interpreter" and then make sure you are using the Python interpreter of your virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

Newer PyGObject versions are dynamically generated and pylance can't understand that.

The best option right now is to work with the generated docs:

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/

There is some work done for including generate stubs in the package but it's not finished:

https://github.com/pygobject/pgi-docgen/pull/176